# Why does a set of double quote comment have effect on real code

Tags: python, comments

This is the code which be reported error `unexpexted indentation`(because of the comment `YOUR CODE HERE` double quoted)

```
    while score0 < goal and score1 < goal:
        if  who == 0:
            num_rolls = strategy0(score0, score1)
            score0 += take_turn(num_rolls, score1, dice)
            who = other(who) if extra_turn(score0, score1) == False else who
        else:
            num_rolls = strategy1(score1, score0)
            score1 += take_turn(num_rolls, score0, dice)
            who = other(who) if extra_turn(score1, score0) == False else who    
    "*** YOUR CODE HERE ***"
```

when I delete the `"*** YOUR CODE HERE ***"`  (same indentation level of while) ,everything works fine.

By the way ,I have never seen a comment with a set of double quote(`" "`).Maybe common format of comment is like `"""  """` or `#`

Answer: the `"*** YOUR CODE HERE ***"` is a string literal.

Comment: No offence, but my answer provided more information :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't a comment, it's a string literal

Answer (score 1):

It still works because it is a string, or more specifically a string literal:

> A string literal or anonymous string is a type of literal for the representation of a string value in the source code of a computer program. [Source](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal&ved=2ahUKEwjF6rjsu7H5AhUaR2wGHXM0AboQmhN6BAgHEAI&usg=AOvVaw13BHpp4PVXeah6-t8rKUc8)

Putting a string like so in the code does absolute nothing, unless put in a function or assignment.